# How to bypass muliple validation attribute values inside validation messages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual, customvalidator, laravel-validation

I've made a custom validator, that compares two dates, and I want to show a message to the user which says the one date (the `invoicedate` in my example) must be earlier than the other one (the `deadline` in my example).

Inside my custom validator I write:

```
public static validateInfo(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'referencenumber' => 'required|min:2|max:64',
        'invoicedate' => 'required|date',
        'deadline' => 'null|date'
    ]);
    $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($request) { // custom static function where I compare two dates using strtotime(), if invoicedate and deadline are still valid, and return false or true
        if (InvoiceValidator::invalidDeadline($validator, $request)) {
            $validator->errors()->add('deadline', __('validation.negative_date_difference', [
                'attribute1' => 'deadline',
                'attribute2' => 'invoicedate'
            ]));
        }
    });
    return $validator;
}
```

---

And inside `resources\lang\en\validation.php` I write:

```
<?php
return [
    // ...
    'negative_date_difference'  => 'The :attribute1 may not be earlier than the :attribute2.',
    // ...
    'attributes' => [
        'referencenumber' => 'Reference Number', // This works. It's fine
        'invoicedate' => 'Invoice Date' // But this does not work, of course, because I wrote $validator->errors()->add('deadline'...); so the deadline is the only targetted attribute name here
    ],
]
```

---

Current output is:

> The Deadline may not be earlier than the invoicedate.

---

**My question**: how to bypass `invoicedate`, when this is the message I want to see?

> The Deadline may not be earlier than the Invoice Date.

Comment: Does [`before`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-before) not already do this?

Comment: I don't know. What do you mean?

Comment: Something like `$rules = [ "invoicedate" => "before:".$request->deadline ]` which would fail with `invoiceDate must be before <the date>` The placeholder for custom message is going to be `:attribute` for the invoice date and `:date` for the other date

Comment: Ah ok... I'll try it. Thank you! I've found 1 solution that works (for now), but I'll try your solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `resources\lang\en\messages.php` I've added a new message:

```
<?php
return [
    'invoice_date' => 'Invoice Date'
]
```

---

Then edited my custom validation function, as follows:

```
if (InvoiceValidator::invalidDeadline($validator, $request)) {
    $validator->errors()->add('deadline', __('validation.negative_date_difference', [
        'attribute1' => 'deadline',
        'attribute2' => __('messages.invoice_date') // This works
    ]));
}
```